# iOS app crashes after idle for a while

Tags: ios, crash

My app crashes after goes idle for a 30 mins. Below is the Crash Report..

The app is loaded but when I try to open a popupover control (WYPopoverControl) it doesn't open and after a while when I focus on any text box it will crash randomly. After the crash, when the app re-opens everything will resume working without issues. How do I debug such issues?

the crash looks like I am not removing the observer from Notification center.. I put the RemoveObserver in the dealloc os all the places required.. but still it crashes

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39a8fb26 objc_msgSend + 6
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2f616116 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 10
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2f58a252 _CFXNotificationPost + 1714
3   Foundation                      0x2ff6fc28 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
4   UIKit                           0x31dcc6b2 -[UIDevice setOrientation:animated:] + 290
5   UIKit                           0x31dcbcfc -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1304
6   UIKit                           0x31dcb71c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
7   UIKit                           0x31e30b38 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 660
8   GraphicsServices                0x342af70a _PurpleEventCallback + 606
9   GraphicsServices                0x342af2f2 PurpleEventCallback + 30
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2f61e9dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2f61e976 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2f61d14a __CFRunLoopRun + 1394
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2f587c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2f587a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
15  GraphicsServices                0x342ae27e GSEventRunModal + 134
16  UIKit                           0x31e2b044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
17  dark                            0x000e7a78 0xe0000 + 31352
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x39f9cab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a04083c kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x39f81210 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x39f80f96 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a052f38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bb224 _pthread_cond_wait + 536
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bc000 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   Foundation                      0x2ffc23f2 -[NSCondition wait] + 190
4   dark                            0x002e11aa 0xe0000 + 2101674
5   Foundation                      0x30037c82 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bbc1a _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bbb8a _pthread_start + 98
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0b9c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a040a8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a040888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2f61e7be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2f61cee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2f587c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2f587a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x2ff753d6 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   Foundation                      0x2ffc630c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
8   dark                            0x003073a0 0xe0000 + 2257824
9   Foundation                      0x30037c82 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bbc1a _pthread_body + 138
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bbb8a _pthread_start + 98
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0b9c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a040a8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a040888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2f61e7be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2f61cee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2f587c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2f587a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x2ffc22f2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 314
7   Foundation                      0x30037c82 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bbc1a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bbb8a _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0b9c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  AFNetworking
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a040a8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a040888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2f61e7be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2f61cee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2f587c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2f587a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x2ff753d6 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   Foundation                      0x2ffc630c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
8   dark                            0x00151150 0xe0000 + 463184
9   Foundation                      0x30037c82 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bbc1a _pthread_body + 138
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bbb8a _pthread_start + 98
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0b9c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a053440 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2f622680 __CFSocketManager + 480
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bbc1a _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bbb8a _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0b9c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a040a8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a040888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2f61e7be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2f61cee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2f587c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2f5cb736 CFRunLoopRun + 94
6   CoreMotion                      0x2fc3e230 ___lldb_unnamed_function1404$$CoreMotion + 724
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bbc1a _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bbb8a _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0b9c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a053c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0b9dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0b9c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a053c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0b9dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0b9c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a053c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0b9dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0b9c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x17f45e70    r1: 0x00333765      r2: 0x1b88c240      r3: 0x00002060
    r4: 0x17f1cbc0    r5: 0x27d21b80      r6: 0x27d21bdc      r7: 0x27d21aa0
    r8: 0x1658a788    r9: 0x756f5935     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00000001
    ip: 0x3a326744    sp: 0x27d21aa0      lr: 0x2f616119      pc: 0x39a8fb26
  cpsr: 0x20000030
```

Comment: try putting `RemoveObserver` in `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: Did you ever solve this one?

@Akhilrajtr - Why would that be better? Dealloc is the right place for it.

Comment: @travoux : Did you solve this issue?IF yes kindly share your solution

Answer (score 2):

you signed up for a notification using addObserver but you never remove yourself as a receiver of that note. using removeObserver (both with the Notification Center).

now your original 'listener' goes away but since it is still registered -- BOOM

so don't forget to unregister yourself!

Comment: I have this added  in all the classes I subscribed to notifications - (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

Comment: before the error? it is definitely because of a UIDeviceOrientationDidChange note

Comment: Still trying.. I looks like there was a memory leak and some objects just disappeared. The weird thing is it happens once in a while and only happens on my device. works fine for all my peers. its a och Ness Monster Bug. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html I am trying to use instruments to gather some clues

Comment: objects don't disappear ;) a memory leak is quite the opposite btw :)

Comment: ic. I saw this popovercontrol (WYPopoverControl)  takes 1.2mb. and adds a new one every time I open it. definitely it will take up all the memory at one point. I checked the memory leak and there is none. (there are a few from firebase library that i am going to ignore)

Comment: I have custom TableView cells. I have subviews drawing chat bubble and a bunch of lables. I have dealloc and I am nullifying all the objects there.. but I see them in the heap even after I exit the view controller.. I wonder why dealloc never gets called on the cells..

Comment: with arc you will rarely have leaks BUT you will often have abandoned memory: memory thats still referenced but not used

Comment: typically it is retain cycles

Answer (score -1):

I have seen similar crashers before. I have two suggestions:
1. Add an observer in viewWillAppear and remove it in viewWillDisAppear
2. Assign your observer to an instance like:

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
self.localObserver = [center addObserverForName:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
                                                   object:self.managedObjectContext queue:mainQueue usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {
                                                      //do something when you get this notification
                                                   }];
```

And then in your viewWillDisAppear unregister it using:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.localObserver];
```

What I have seen is dealloc is not called in iOS 8. It is only called when you receive memory warning. So try not to unregister there. In earlier versions, it used to work like that.

Note: In the code snippet above, I am observing NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. You can change it as per your requirement.

Comment: it's better to use -viewDidAppear: and -viewDidDisappear:, because calls to that function are always matched. In iOS 7+, -viewWillAppear does not mean that the view will really appear: it just means that it started to appear. E.g. if the user does a back-swipe-gesture in a navigation view controller and finally decides that he doesn't want to swipe back (i.e. he cancels the gesture), -viewWillAppear will be called, but at the end the view is still invisible. when the user pushes the back button, -viewWillAppear: is called again.